# How to insert empty row in Google Spreadsheets when two rows are not duplicate?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number of rows in a Google spreadsheet. I want to insert an empty row only when two sequential rows are not duplicate. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?